# JAVAFX How can I create a method for setting objects visible?

Tags: javafx

I am new to Java and JavaFX so sorry if this question seems a bit obvious but it is doing my head in. I have tried googling solutions but haven't been able to find anything so far.

Basically I am trying to re-use some code in Java FX to hide / show some objects when a button is pressed. Rather than copy / paste the whole code again, I want to put it in a method (or something similar) that gets called on different occasions.

So here is a simple code example that I hope explains what I am trying to do:

```
package src;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage; 

public class example extends Application
{ 
    @Override    
    public void start(Stage stage)  
    {
        Button b1 = new Button(); 
        b1.setText("Show Label 1 Only");
        
        Button b2 = new Button(); 
        b2.setText("Show Label 2 Only");
        
        Button b3 = new Button();
        b3.setText("Show Label 2 and 3");
        
        Label l1 = new Label();
        l1.setText("Label 1");
        
        Label l2 = new Label();
        l2.setText("Label 2");
        
        Label l3 = new Label();
        l3.setText("Label 3");
        
        
        b1.setOnAction(e -> 
        {
            l1.setVisible(true);
            l2.setVisible(false);
            l3.setVisible(false);
            
        });

        b2.setOnAction(e -> 
        {
            l1.setVisible(false);
            l2.setVisible(true);
            l3.setVisible(false);
            
        });

        b3.setOnAction(e -> 
        {
            l1.setVisible(false);
            l2.setVisible(true);
            l3.setVisible(true);
            
        });


        VBox root = new VBox();         
        root.setSpacing(10);         
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 
        
        l1.setVisible(false);
        l2.setVisible(false);
        l3.setVisible(false);
        
        root.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2, b3, l1, l2, l3); 
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);  
        
        stage.setScene(scene);         
        stage.setTitle("Example");         
        stage.show();         
        
}

    public static void main(String[] args)     
    {         
        launch(args);     
    } 
}
```

As you can see, the first 2 lines of the code for B2 and B3 are the same, so it would be nice if I could just put these lines in a method that gets called in both scenarios. This is in essence what i am trying to achieve.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Like I said, I'm new to JAVA / JAVAFX so sorry if it seems like an obvious question.

Comment: Make the labels instance variables and just define a method that takes three booleans indicating whether each label should be visible or not.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to make the labels instance variables and just to define a method taking a boolean for each one, indicating if it should be visible:

```
public class Example extends Application { 

    private Label l1;
    private Label l2;
    private Label l3;

    private void labelVisibility(boolean l1Visible, boolean l2Visible, boolean l3Visible) {
        l1.setVisible(l1Visible);
        l2.setVisible(l2Visible);
        l3.setVisible(l3Visible);
    }

    @Override    
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button b1 = new Button(); 
        b1.setText("Show Label 1 Only");
        
        Button b2 = new Button(); 
        b2.setText("Show Label 2 Only");
        
        Button b3 = new Button();
        b3.setText("Show Label 2 and 3");
        
        l1 = new Label();
        l1.setText("Label 1");
        
        l2 = new Label();
        l2.setText("Label 2");
        
        l3 = new Label();
        l3.setText("Label 3");
        
        
        b1.setOnAction(e -> labelVisibility(true, false, false));

        b2.setOnAction(e -> labelVisibility(false, true, false));

        b3.setOnAction(e -> labelVisibility(false, true, true));


        VBox root = new VBox();         
        root.setSpacing(10);         
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 
        
        labelVisibility(false, false, false);
        
        root.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2, b3, l1, l2, l3); 
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);  
        
        stage.setScene(scene);         
        stage.setTitle("Example");         
        stage.show();         
        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        launch(args);     
    } 
}
```

If you don't want to expand the scope of the labels (and want a bit more generality), your method can take a list of all the labels, and a list of the ones you want visible:

```
public class Example extends Application { 


    private void labelVisibility(List<Node> allNodes, Node... visibleNodes) {
        List<Node> visibleNodeList = Arrays.asList(visibleNodes);
        for (Node node : allNodes) {
            node.setVisible(visibleNodeList.contains(node));
        }
    }

    @Override    
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button b1 = new Button(); 
        b1.setText("Show Label 1 Only");
        
        Button b2 = new Button(); 
        b2.setText("Show Label 2 Only");
        
        Button b3 = new Button();
        b3.setText("Show Label 2 and 3");
        
        Label l1 = new Label();
        l1.setText("Label 1");
        
        Label l2 = new Label();
        l2.setText("Label 2");
        
        Label l3 = new Label();
        l3.setText("Label 3");
        
        List<Node> allLabels = List.of(l1, l2, l3);
        
        b1.setOnAction(e -> labelVisibility(allLabels, l1));

        b2.setOnAction(e -> labelVisibility(allLabels, l2));

        b3.setOnAction(e -> labelVisibility(allLabels, l2, l3));


        VBox root = new VBox();         
        root.setSpacing(10);         
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 
        
        labelVisibility(allLabels);
        
        root.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2, b3, l1, l2, l3); 
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);  
        
        stage.setScene(scene);         
        stage.setTitle("Example");         
        stage.show();         
        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        launch(args);     
    } 
}
```